# How to mock an external dependency method callback params in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

Let's say that I have the following:

**lib/modules/module1.js**

```
var m2 = require('module2');

module.exports = function(){
    return {
        // ...
        get: function(cb){
            m2.someMethod(params, function(error, data){
                if(error){
                    cb(error)
                }

                cb(null, data)
            })
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now let's say that I have a set of tests in another dir, e.g. **tests/testModule1.js**. From this file, I create an instance of `module1` to peform some tests.

I would like to mock the objects passed by the `m2.someMethod` to it's callback function (not the `cb` function), from the file **testModule1.js**.

I've looked into [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/), but I couldn't figure a way to do this. Actually, I that even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Answered similar question that could be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/39181844/594589

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like `proxyquire`, but I'm not a fan of modifying the built in `require`.

Personally, I would suggest rewriting your code to use dependency injection:

```
module.exports = function(m2){
    return {
        // ...
        get: function(cb){
            m2.someMethod(params, function(error, data){
                if(error){
                    cb(error)
                }

                cb(null, data)
            })
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that I moved `m2` to be a parameter in your exported function. Then somewhere else (app, or main, or whatever), you could do this:

#### app.js

```
var module1Creator = require('module1');
var module2 = require('module2');
var module1 = module1Creator(module2);
```

Then when you need to test it...

#### testModule1.js

```
var module1Creator = require('module1');
// inject the "fake" version containing test data, spies, etc
var module2Mocked = require('module2mock');
var module1 = module1Creator(module2mocked);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would normaly agree that about changing the design and, as suggested by @dvlsg, DI would be my choice as well.

However, the project I'm working on is already on the move, and has a considerable size. By doing this change would imply in a huge manpower cost that, in this case specifically, might not be worth doing it.

As a solution, I've realized that once you do a `require('someModule')`, the *someModule* is loaded and it's stored as a singleton, in some sort of global cache (I don't fully understand this mechanism, but I'll look into it), and doesn't matter if you `require('someModule')` from another file, you will receive the cached version.

So, if in **lib/modules/module1.js** I do `require('module2')`, *module2* is loaded and stored in this cache and, I can `require('module2')` and mock it in **tests/testModule1.js**. This will reflect when the `get()` from **lib/modules/module1.js** is called.

For that, I used [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to create the mocks in the test files.

The procedure above **actually solved** my problem, in a way that I didn't have to change the whole design, and I was able to do the tests. Thats why I'm posting this as an answer. However, I'll not set this as the correct answer here because, as I said before, I don't fully understand this mechanism and change required modules is not a good practice.

I would like to see what other devs have to say about this and, if the discussion leads to acceptance, I'll ultimately set this as correct.