# How to unit test a function which calls another that returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, sinon

I have a node.js app using express 4 and this is my controller:

```
var service = require('./category.service');

module.exports = {
  findAll: (request, response) => {
    service.findAll().then((categories) => {
      response.status(200).send(categories);
    }, (error) => {
      response.status(error.statusCode || 500).json(error);
    });
  }
};
```

It calls my service which returns a promise. Everything works but I am having trouble when trying to unit test it.

Basically, I would like to make sure that based on what my service returns, I flush the response with the right status code and body.

So with mocha and sinon it looks something like:

```
it('Should call service to find all the categories', (done) => {
    // Arrange
    var expectedCategories = ['foo', 'bar'];

    var findAllStub = sandbox.stub(service, 'findAll');
    findAllStub.resolves(expectedCategories);

    var response = {
       status: () => { return response; },
       send: () => {}
    };
    sandbox.spy(response, 'status');
    sandbox.spy(response, 'send');

    // Act
    controller.findAll({}, response);

    // Assert
    expect(findAllStub.called).to.be.ok;
    expect(findAllStub.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(response.status).to.be.calledWith(200); // not working
    expect(response.send).to.be.called; // not working
    done();
});
```

I have tested my similar scenarios when the function I am testing returns itself a promise since I can hook my assertions in the then.

I also have tried to wrap controller.findAll with a Promise and resolve it from the response.send but it didn't work neither.

Comment: Every function that calls a promise-returning function is asynchronous and should return a promise itself. If you only take callbacks, then you have to fall back to testing a callback-based API.

Comment: Are you using Chai? If so, http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

Comment: Yes but the function I am testing does not return a promise son chain-as-promised does not help mere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should move your assert section into the `res.send` method to make sure all async tasks are done before the assertions:

```
var response = {
   status: () => { return response; },
   send: () => {
     try {
       // Assert
       expect(findAllStub.called).to.be.ok;
       expect(findAllStub.callCount).to.equal(1);
       expect(response.status).to.be.calledWith(200); // not working
       // expect(response.send).to.be.called; // not needed anymore
       done();
     } catch (err) {
       done(err);
     }
   },
};
```

Comment: Yes, now it works. However, if I try the test have it failing (compare status to 204, let´s say), it does not show the failing assertion. It just times out and say:  `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

Comment: @jbernal my bad, forgot that you have to catch the thrown error and pass it to `done`, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks so much. Using the try/catch blocks have saved me.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to have the promise which `service.findAll()` returns accessible inside the test's code without calling the `service`. As far as I can see `sinon-as-promised` which you probably use does not allow to do so. So I just used a native `Promise` (hope your node version is not too old for it).

```
const aPromise = Promise.resolve(expectedCategories); 
var findAllStub = sandbox.stub(service, 'findAll');
findAllStub.returns(aPromise);

// response = { .... }

controller.findAll({}, response);

aPromise.then(() => {
    expect(response.status).to.be.calledWith(200);
    expect(response.send).to.be.called;    
});
```

Comment: I know this scenario. But if you realise, my `controller.findAll` does not return a promise, it doesn't need it to. And thus,my problem. I cannot perform a then in it.

Comment: @jbernal, I see your point. I've mixed up `findAll`s. Won't it help if you call `controller.findAll()` and after that chain `service.findAll()`, i.e.

    `constoller.findAll();
    service.findAll().then(() => {
        expect(....)
    });`

Comment: Don't think so... `controller.findAll` is the one calling `service.findAll` and that is one of the things under test, so I don't want to be calling it explicitly in it.

Comment: if you don't want to return the promise, you could stub `res.send` instead of spying on it and check your tests when res.send is called

Comment: @jbernal, please see a corrected version in the answer. I've removed my initial code because it doesn't answer anything.

Comment: @JohannesMerz, changing the spy for a stub does not solve it neither. It doesn't get called at all as before.

Comment: @ViktorMolokostov yes, now it works. However, if I try the test to fail, it does not show the failing assertion. It just times out and say:  `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

Comment: @jbernal, I don't see the actual code you have now, but probably that is because Mocha waits for a promise to be resolved when it is used as a return value of a test. For testing an error case you still have to use `done()` i.e. `aPromise.catch(() => { /* assertions */; done() })`.

Answer (score 1):

When code is difficult to test it can indicate that there could be different design possibilities to explore, which promote easy testing.  What jumps out is that `service` is enclosed in your module, and the dependency is not exposed at all.  I feel like the goal shouldn't be to find a way to test your code AS IS but to find an optimal design.

IMO The goal is to find a way to expose `service` so that your test can provide a stubbed implementation, so that the logic of `findAll` can be tested in isolation, synchronously.

One way to do this is to use a library like `mockery` or `rewire`.  Both are fairly easy to use, (in my experience mockery starts to degrade and become very difficult to maintain as your test suite and number of modules grow)  They would allow you to patch the `var service = require('./category.service');` by providing your own service object with its own `findAll` defined.

Another way is to rearchitect your code to expose the `service` to the caller, in some way.  This would allow your caller (the unit test) to provide its own `service` stub.

One easy way to do this would be to export a function contstructor instead of an object.

```
module.exports = (userService) => {

  // default to the required service
  this.service = userService || service;

  this.findAll = (request, response) => {
    this.service.findAll().then((categories) => {
      response.status(200).send(categories);
    }, (error) => {
      response.status(error.statusCode || 500).json(error);
    });
  }
};

var ServiceConstructor = require('yourmodule');
var service = new ServiceConstructor();
```

Now the test can create a stub for `service` and provide it to the `ServiceConstructor` to exercise the `findAll` method.  Removing the need for an asynchronous test altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. These are definitely ideas I need to look into. I am working on my first node application and I am sure there are more optimal and better structured patterns that I can follow to improve my code. I will try to implement them. Cheers